# Cannot connect to mongo running locally via docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've scoured the web for clues as to why when I try to connect to mongo I get a constant case of connection timeouts, to no avail. I've created my docker-compose file and made it look like so:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  meteodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: meteodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Super simple, super basic. Then, to test and verify my connection I've went ahead and tried to connect via the Compass GUI using the following connection string: `mongodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017`. However, all I ever get is just a connection timeout. Looking at my running container, I do not see any specific logs of a connection being made nor attempted.

```
meteoweatherapi-mongodb_container-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-09T03:15:34.197+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
meteoweatherapi-mongodb_container-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-09T03:15:34.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
meteoweatherapi-mongodb_container-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-09T03:15:34.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
meteoweatherapi-mongodb_container-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-09T03:15:34.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Only thing that catches my eye is the address portion. Where exactly am I going awry? All of the documentation that I've seen (along with what I used to do a few years ago when I used Mongo via docker) was to just create such a basic compose file and proceed from there.

Comment: Indentation is wanky in stackoverflow. I have the vs code extension for it so I assume that indent is fine in it. As for the ctx, what exactly is the correct format? AS far as I can tell, that is how it should be? Per https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/ since it is not an srv, I do not need it. Thus it would become mongodb://[user]:[password]@[host]

Comment: @Phil, I have edited my question. I decided to omit the volume as I do not actually need it for this use case. Even with above template, it still wouldn't play nice

Comment: Could you please update the log output? It no longer matches your compose configuration.

Comment: No need, it still the same output. Only difference is the left hand will now read meteodb instead of meteoweatherapi-mongodb_container-1